# ASP.NET Encrypt/decrypt and Unicode Encoding different strings lenghts

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, unicode

I've a mechanism of Encrypting and Decrypting in ASP.NET 4.6 / VB.NET

In Decrypting i use
            .......

```
        y="zoSObQFhc+GJSUrnAmagZ2/uuunFrCUv" ' String received

        Dim cipherBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(y)

        Dim msDecrypt As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(cipherBytes)
        Dim csDecrypt As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
        Dim fromEncrypt As Byte() = New Byte(cipherBytes.Length - 1) {}
        csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length)
        Dim x as string = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(fromEncrypt)
```

I passed a crypted (with variable y) string and the result is correct and get back the orinal word "procedure" (without quotes)  in variable x.

Print x produces "procedure" (without quotes)

Only the Lenght of x is 12.

Now if  try to check

```
if x = "procedure"....
```

Test is false.

Where i get wrong ?

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF-16; perhaps you intended `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: It's the same also with UTF8 produces same

Comment: I can skip with StrComp(x, y, CompareMethod.Text) but i would like understand

Comment: You could use `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x).Select(Function(b) Hex(b))))` to see what the bytes of the string are - perhaps a zero byte sneaked in there somewhere. But if `CompareMethod.Text` makes it work, that suggests that there is a case difference - was the original string "procedure" or was it "procEdure", or something else with an uppercase letter?

Comment: `Dim fromEncrypt As Byte() = New Byte(cipherBytes.Length - 1)` - that isn't what the length of the decrypted data will be. Please see [Can the length of a CryptoStream be determined before decryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239442/can-the-length-of-a-cryptostream-be-determined-before-decryption). Perhaps `Dim x as string = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(fromEncrypt).TrimEnd(Chr(0))` would work.

Answer (score 0):

After applying

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x).Select(Function(b) Hex(b)))
```

**Results:**

String Decrypted:    70 72 6F 63 65 64 75 72 61 0 0 0

Fixed String         70 72 6F 63 65 64 75 72 61

Following is all process to go and back (Enc/Dec)

String to Encrypt: **procedura**

```
{Bytes Length=18}
   (0): 112    (1): 0    (2): 114    (3): 0   (4): 111    (5): 0    
   (6): 99    (7): 0 (8): 101    (9): 0    (10): 100    
   (11): 0    (12): 117    (13): 0    (14): 114      
   (15): 0    (16): 97    (17): 0
```

**After Encryption**

```
{Bytes  Length=24}
(0): 69 (1): 124 (2): 24 (3): 126
(4): 25 (5): 33 (6): 230 (7): 191 
(8): 101 (9): 220 (10): 115  (11): 122 
(12): 174 (13): 156
(14): 156 (15): 213 (16): 62 (17): 119
(18): 31  (19): 177 (20): 139 (21): 17
(22): 132  (23): 88
```

**After Convert.ToBase64String:**

```
RXwYfhkh5r9l3HN6rpyc1T53H7GLEYRY
```

**String Received To Decrypt**

```
RXwYfhkh5r9l3HN6rpyc1T53H7GLEYRY

Dim cipherBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(Data)

>? cipherBytes

{Bytes Length=24}
    (0): 69    (1): 124    (2): 24    (3): 126
    (4): 25    (5): 33    (6): 230    (7): 191
    (8): 101    (9): 220    (10): 115    (11): 122
    (12): 174    (13): 156    (14): 156    (15): 213
    (16): 62    (17): 119    (18): 31    (19): 177
    (20): 139    (21): 17    (22): 132    (23): 88
```

**After Decryption**

```
{Bytes Length=24}
    (0): 112 (1): 0 (2): 114    (3): 0    (4): 111    (5): 0
    (6): 99    (7): 0    (8): 101    (9): 0    (10): 100    (11): 0
    (12): 117    (13): 0    (14): 114    (15): 0    (16): 97    (17): 0
    (18): 0   (19): 0    (20): 0   (21): 0    (22): 0    (23): 0
```

String Decrypted **procedura**